# "Hiding" overridden methods in Java

Tags: java, overriding

Let's say I have some class

```java
public class Foo {
    public void foo(int number) {
        // Do some foo-ing of the given number
    }
}
```

and another class extending it

```java
public class FooExtension extends Foo {
    public void foo(String text) {
        super.foo(text.length());
    }
}
```

And let's say that if you are using a `FooExtension` object, you really shouldn't be calling the `foo(int number)` method, but instead only use `foo(String text)`.

It's not possible to override the `foo(int number)` method of the original class with a lower visibility since that breaks contract when I assign a `FooExtension` instance to a `Foo` variable.

Is there a way that is considered "good practice" to indicate that if you are using `FooExtension`, you really shouldn't be calling the original version of `foo` any more? Maybe overriding it and marking it deprecated? Or overriding it and having it throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`?

Comment: IMO, document it and throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: Yes you can override and throw UnsopportedOperationException but if you do that cause you can't do anymore then write it explicity in javadoc, but think about relationship between Foo and FooExtension  is not as you think(inheritance `IS A` relationship).. You sure if you do that breaks liskov substitution principle

Comment: If you don't want that method to be used, maybe inheritance is not want you want. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: @exception1 Problem is: I'm only modifying the behavior of one of many functions and I'd rather not have a hundred `public void blah(...) { baseclass.blah(...); }`s flying around...

Comment: @MarkusA. You will probably need to re-think your object model then.

Comment: There really is no *is-a* relationship here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way that is considered "good practice" to indicate that if you are using FooExtension, you really shouldn't be calling the original version of foo any more? Maybe overriding it and marking it deprecated? Or overriding it and having it throw an UnsupportedOperationException?

It's hard to define a "good practice", when you are kind of starting with a "bad practice". If you are inheriting from a class, but you *don't* want some of the methods of the parent class, then you shouldn't be using inheritance at all!

Is it possible? Yes, it is possible to do what you want:

```
public class FooExtension extends Foo {

    @Override
    public void foo(int number) {
        throw new UsupportedOperationException("Operation is not supported");
    }

    public void foo(String text) {
        super.foo(text.length());
    }
}
```

But I think designing something like this is bad. Users of your code would likely be surprised if they tried to call a method that belongs to the supertype and got an exception instead.

In cases like this, it is much better to use composition instead of inheritance. That way you can simply delegate *only* the calls you want, to your internal instance.

**EDIT**

Public inheritance is an "is a" relationship. So from the perspective of someone who is using your class, they would expect `FooExtension` to behave like `Foo`, except with some additional behavior. By doing what you are doing, you're violating that definition.

Another thing your design violates is the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). The principle says that if you have a subtype `S` of a type `T`, then replacing objects of type `T` with objects of type `S` should not alter the behavior of your program.

If one were to follow your design, replacing instances of `Foo` with `FooExtension` will cause your program to fail. This is why what you're trying to do is not really recommended.

Comment: Problem is: I'm only modifying the behavior of one of many functions and I'd rather not have a hundred `public void blah(...) { baseclass.blah(...); }`s flying around... Think of it as overriding an OutputStream to handle longs rather than bytes. You don't want the byte-version of "write" to be called any more, but you still want close, flush, and whatever else to stay the same...

Comment: @MarkusA. There is no way to "hide" it, but there is a way to ensure that the users cannot call it. However, I think this is a sign that you might have to re-think your design.

Comment: @MarkusA. But an `OutputStream` *is* a class that represents an output stream of bytes.  The javadoc says so right up front.  If you want an "output stream of longs", then it can't really be called an "is-a" inheritance relationship.  I realize this is just an example, but your case is probably very similar, i.e. it's not really an "is-a" relationship but just a way to try to reuse code.  If that's the case, your original class should perhaps be broken up.

Comment: @ajb Good point... Technically it is still an OutputStream, though, and you could potentially envision scenarios where someone has an array of bytes already that correctly represent longs and might want to skip over an additional conversion step. So, I definitely would not want to throw an exception, but did want to have something to remind me that I need to be careful if I want to skip the abstraction layer and go straight to the stream. That's why I was thinking to use deprecated...

Comment: @MarkusA. [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) will give you a few more ideas.

Comment: Agreed. I'm actually working on a case where I have an abstraction stack of objects and this issue is coming up in protected methods only, so it's not going to break any contract. I think of it as conceptually equivalent to what happens when you override a class's constructor with something with different parameters, where you then can't use the old one any more in future extensions.

Comment: @MarkusA. Ah, but constructors are special :) There is no way you could legally do `Foo foo = new FooExtension(<Foo's constructor arguments>)` if `FooExtension` requires different parameters. Basically you can't even create an instance. But what you are doing is different because you already have instances and you are introducing potentially-contradicting behavior. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an override. It is an overload. Overloads hide the method they overload if the overloaded method is in a base class. This is a fundamental rule of Java and also of C++.

The answer to your question is therefore that it already happens.

Comment: Not sure I'm following... If I have a `new FooExtension()`, I can still call its `foo(int number)` method just fine, no?

Comment: No you can't. Try it.

Comment: @EJP I just tried it and it works fine.  Are you maybe confusing it with a different rule?  (There's a rule about methods hiding methods declared in an *outer* class, not a _superclass_.)